# VSCode find command string from command window

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my vim plugin I would like to bind `<space>-t` to `View: Toggle Integrated Terminal`

What I have so far is:

```
"vim.otherModesKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
      "before": [
        "<leader> t"
      ],
      "after": [],
      "commands": [
        {
          "command": ":DONT KNOW HOW TO FIND WHAT I NEED HERE",
          "args": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

My question is how can I find the command that is used in the command windows so that I can easily setup my vim configuration?

Update:
So I found that I could use: `workbench.action.terminal.focus`. However this does not work when im in the terminal. I would like to be able to use `<leader> t` in the terminal also to get back to the place where i jumped from.

Comment: Do you want to jump back or hide terminal?

Comment: Not sure. The one that makes for the best workflow.

Comment: It doesn't support `when` https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/2030